# Prometheus Alert sum by 1 label but output 2 labels

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

There is a metric(histogram) that has "host" and "error" labels. The value is amount of time the error took. I need to alert whenever the summary of errors for the host get some point. The expression works fine

```
sum by(host)(some_metric_sum / some_metric_sum_count) > 60
```

But this expression returns me only values with `host` label. But I need to have `error` labels as well. Is there any way to join the error labels that were summed in the expression and output them too?

Comment: Hi, re https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13163/prometheus-alert-sum-by-1-label-but-output-2-labels - please avoid cross-posting the same exact question on multiple SE sites - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/cross-posting/info

Comment: Thanks, I have just deleted the question from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sum by (host, error) (some_metric_sum / some_metric_sum_count) > 60
```

Comment: but this way it will sum by each unique error. And I need to sum all the errors for a specific host. Is it possible to output (host and error) labels, but sum all errors for a host?

Comment: No, this is not possible.